# What's the earliest researched based evidence for Holi?

Tags: india, historical-research, hinduism, festival

[Holi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi) is an important festival in Hinduism, generally falling between the months of February to April, as per the relevant calculations of the Hindu Luni-solar calendar.

I'd like to have an account from some of the earliest known research based references and works, for this festival.

How has the said festival developed and evolved, over time until present?

---

I'd like an account not from within the Hindu scriptures cannon basex research, but through the research lenses of sociology and/or anthropology culture based relevant studies.

Comment: Hi Vivikta and welcome to History SE. At first glance, this might be a bit broad as this is covering a lot of time. Also, it would help if you could explain what you think is missing from the Wiki article you linked to. Do the sources in that article help at all?

Comment: I'd suggest trimming to something along the lines of "What's the earliest written historical reference to Holi?" Perhaps, "How was it different then?" might be OK as an addon. Asking for a recitation of its entire history in the years/centuries/millennia since is more than a bit too much.